# Assigning static ip in linux

Tags: linux, debian, static-ip-address

I've tried to assign static ip to my raspberry computer, yet it doesn't assign it after rebooting. My /etc/networ/interfaces file looks like this:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
#iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

After rebooting and using ifconfig command it shows me that the address is different. What should I do to make it assign data from the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `/etc/network/interfaces` not `/etc/networ/interfaces` and you forgot to add:

```
 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet static
```

You should do:

```
 /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

or

```
 ifdown eth0 
 ifup eth0
```

Instead of rebooting, Also make sure that `192.168.1.2` isn't used already.

Comment: Yep, I've missed that letter while noting the path name. Nevertheless, adding 'eth0' after 'auto' in the file helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
auto lo
```

to

```
auto lo eth0
```

As this will make `ifup -a` run during system startup configure eth0 as well. (see `man interfaces`).